# Ruby On Rails, Error running command "rails generate controller", Input/output error @ rb_sysopen, (Errno::EIO)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the beginning, when I run `rails generate controller welcome homepage` into my project's dir, the command works OK and produces the `app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb` and route `get welcome/homepage`

```
User1@My-Machine:~/MyProject$ rails generate controller welcome homepage
/home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:39: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/User1/.rbenv/versions in PATH, mode 040777
      create  app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb
       route  get 'welcome/homepage'
```

immediately after that, the command runs into the following error:

```
/home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/inject_into_file.rb:98:in `binread': Input/output error @ rb_sysopen - /home/User1/MyProject/config/routes.rb (Errno::EIO)
```

followed by a list of files.

```
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/inject_into_file.rb:98:in `replace!'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/inject_into_file.rb:59:in `invoke!'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:94:in `action'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/inject_into_file.rb:30:in `insert_into_file'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/generators/actions.rb:224:in `block in route'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:194:in `block in in_root'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:184:in `block in inside'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:128:in `chdir'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:128:in `cd'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:184:in `inside'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:194:in `in_root'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/generators/actions.rb:223:in `route'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/generators/rails/controller/controller_generator.rb:16:in `block in add_routes'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/generators/rails/controller/controller_generator.rb:15:in `reverse_each'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/generators/rails/controller/controller_generator.rb:15:in `add_routes'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/generators.rb:157:in `invoke'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/generate.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in `require_command!'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:130:in `generate_or_destroy'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:50:in `generate'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /home/User1/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Does anyone know how this can be resolved?

Comment: As the error says `/home/User1/MyProject/config/routes.rb` file is missing, please check whether you have routes file.  This error comes when rails trying to add  the line `get 'welcome/homepage'` in your config/routes.rb

Comment: @sssskkk. Strange, in Bash seems that the file is missing. In windows file system I can see it's there! I tried to replace it from a similar project with `cp routes.rb ../../test1/config` but I get the message `cp: cannot create regular file ‘../../test1/config/routes.rb’: Input/output error`. Then I copied it from windows but It's still missing. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is a bit of a copout, but my experience with the current versions of WSL is that rbenv has issues running in WSL, wheras RVM seems to work okay. The original question sounds like you may be moving linux specific files like /home/user/file (from the appdata area) from the Windows interface -- definitely [don't do that. Only manipulate those files from bash, as corruption and oddities will occur](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/402).

Not sure why things aren't being created or seen correctly in your setup, but in general, here's what has worked for me:

Using RVM, and with the help of [this guy](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/451#issuecomment-227774250) I came to the conclusion that I need to

```
bundle config --delete bin
rake rails:update:bin
git add bin
```

and use

```
bash --login
```

to log into the interactive version of bash from Windows.

I've been successfully creating and working with projects from both Bash and Windows in the mounted space, i.e. `/mnt/c/Users/Tim/Desktop/railsapp`

I run generators and whatnot from bash, but edit the content of the files from Sublime in Windows.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes! with RVM and the above fix works fine! Please also add that `git init` should run before `git add bin` in case it is not initialized. The use of mounted space is also a good idea. Thanks a lot!