# uninitialized constant Api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I am still a beginner concerning ruby on rails and I am trying to create a simple API but I am facing this error :"uninitialized constant Api"

***ideas_controller.rb***

```
module Api
 module V1
  class ItemsController < BaseController
    def index
     @ideas = Idea.all
     render json: @ideas
    end
  end
 end
end
```

***routes.db***

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :ideas  
    end
  end
end
```

***application_controller.rb***

```
   class ApplicationController < ActionController
 protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

end
```

***base_controller.rb***

```
   module Api
 module V1
class BaseController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
end
end
```

**The project's directories:**

[image: project tree]

**The server's error:**
[image]

I have also tried this approach and changed the project's structure to :
[image: Directorie's updated]

Also, I have enabled :
  config.eager_load = true
After that I got the following error:

**`block in load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant Api::V1::BaseController (NameError)**

Comment: Did you put your `ideas_controller.rb` in api namespace like so `app/controllers/api/v1/ideas_controller.rb`?

Comment: please, show the full path to your ideas_controller.rb

Comment: Yes, I did.
Here's the full path :
contact-api/app/controllers/api/v1/ideas_controller.rb

Answer (score 3):

If you're in the development environment, eager loading is turned off by default, which can be fixed by turning on eager load (change to `config.eager_load = true` in `config/development.rb`). Eager loading will allow the whole Rails app to be loaded when the server starts (which is slightly slower), but will fix your problem since that file will be loaded.

Comment: @RowanX That doesn't make a difference, what I said is still applicable.

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error because `module Api` is not defined before, I guess if you made like this it gonna work. from an answer [here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/145121)

```
module Api
 module V1
  class IdeasController < ApplicationController
    def index
     @ideas = Idea.all
     render json: @ideas
    end
  end
 end
end
```

another solution could be like this:

```
module Api
 module V1
 end
end
class Api::V1::IdeasController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @ideas = Idea.all
   render json: @ideas
  end
end
```

hope it helps.

Comment: I have tried them, actually I have tried one of them before modifying my code and still getting the same error.

Comment: hmmm, Could you update your question with `route`,  `directory tree` of the project and more about the error message appear in the rails server, Cuz it according to your comments above it should work.
One more question: did you restart the server after adding the the directories and tried one of my solutions?

Comment: Yes, I have made sure that I restart the server after each trial.
I have updated the question details.

Comment: Sorry, I need to ask you more questions:
1- I noticed you are inheriting from `ApplicationController` without finding it you directory tree, I should be a file with `class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base;end`.
2- Did you trie to type `Api::V1::IdeasController` on rails console?

Comment: I actually appreciate your effort.
1- I don't quite understand your statement, Do you mean I should create a base controller first and then inherit from it?
2-Yes, and it gave me the following error:
  1: from (irb):1
NameError (uninitialized constant Api)

Comment: You're totally welcome, Yes I mean what about creating `ApplicationController` under `/app/controller` and make it inherits from `ActionController::Base`, did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your ideas controller

```
module Api
 module V1
  class IdeasController < Api::V1::BaseController
   def index
    @ideas = Idea.all
    render json: @ideas
   end
  end
 end
end
```

And define your base controller in the following way

```
class Api::V1::BaseController < ApplicationController
 respond_to :json
end
```

Comment: still got "uninitialized constant Api::V1::BaseController (NameError)".

Comment: Try recreating your files again with following 
`rails generate controller Api/V1/Base`  
`rails generate controller Api/V1/Ideas index`

Comment: That produced an error:
" Input/output error @ dir_s_mkdir - /home=/contacts-api/app/controllers/api (Errno::EIO)"

Comment: maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40377637/ruby-on-rails-error-running-command-rails-generate-controller-input-output-e?answertab=votes#tab-top